# how to debug wpa_supplicant in android?

Tags: android, adb

My specific questions are:

- 1. How to change the debug level to MSG_DEBUG of wpa_supplicant in
     Android?
  2. Do I need to compile the wpa_supplicant to achieve this goal?
  3. How to view the logs?

I had tried to use these commands:

> 1. `adb shell wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -d`
> 2. `adb logcat | grep -i "wpa_supplicant"`

But these commands didn't bring up `MSG_DEBUG` level logs.

I tried to use the conf file in /system/etc/wifi directory. i.e.

> `adb shell wpa_supplicant -c/system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -d`

But this give me an error:

> mkdir[ctrl_interface]: Read-only file system

I didn't find a workaround for this. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the wpa_common.c file,you can find the wpa_printf function output the debug log,you cant use MSG_DEBUG as a parameter,that's you question 1 and 2

Comment: the question 3 you can use this command "logcat busybox grep -i wpa_supplicant(I'm on by board ,so maybe a little difference)"

Comment: on default, the /system directory can't be read and write,if you want to excute the applicantion,you should remount the /system directory by command "busybox mount -o remount,rw /system",if you want to start the supplicant,you need to give the write interface name and driver name,if it can't start rightly, please catch the log to find why

Comment: Thank you cheny. How can I set the MSG_DEBUG parameter? Should I set them in the source code and flash the phone? Or can I use some command in terminal to change the parameter?

Comment: these parameter is added by yourself, if you don't know how to add it, you can download a right copy from the internet, the directory is "/JellyBean/external/wpa_supplicant_8/src/common", maybe it's not the same as yours, but it's approximately there.

Answer (score 8):

For

1. Try wpa_cli loglevel command to change the log level
2. System partition is read only partition, use `-c /data/misc/wifi/` as
   that folder is created for wpa_supplicant
3. Logs can be viewed via logcat: `adb logcat wpa_supplicant:V *:S`

Comment: is there a way to get the wpa_supplicant logs via a non root app in java?

Comment: I'm gifting you goodwill for providing the very useful logcat.  This is essential for debugging in realtime.